# Import third partiy control to own assembly in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, dll

I have a bunch of winform control libraries in my visual studio 2008 after I installed a third party.
How can I import those controls to my own custom library? For example 
Instead of using `ThirdPartyAssembly.ControlName` I can use `MyAssembly.CotrolName` (all controls still have full functionality the same as the original)

Can anyone please give me an example?

Comment: The reason that I want to do like this is i have two different versions of my third-party controls and I cannot add them to my project reference with the same assembly name then I just want to repackaging one of them to my own assembly so that I can use all the controls inside the two assembly.

Comment: Side note: it is likley will be license violation to repackage someone elses library as your own. Read license/contact author(s) before doing so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not import thirdparty controls into your own library. You can only reference them. You can use [namespace alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) feature if want to reference these controls in code under a different name:

```
using MyNamespace = ThirdPartyNamespace;
...

var control = new MyNamespace.ControlName();
```

If you are dealing with two versions of the same thirdparty dll you can use [extern alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx). Read [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rambab/Assembly04292006002740AM/Assembly.aspx) or [this](http://kentb.blogspot.com/2008/11/visual-studio-referencing-same-assembly.html):

```
extern alias ThirdPartyAssemblyV1;
extern alias ThirdPartyAssemblyV2;
...
var v1 = new ThirdPartyAssemblyV1::Namespace.ControlName();
var v2 = new ThirdPartyAssemblyV2::Namespace.ControlName();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me try this.

Answer (score 0):

It's seem like not possible. You can reference it. But another way can do it, package two difference library as assembly's resource, reflection to call method after extract to disk.

Comment: Is there a snippet you can provide?